# How to get created date column of sharepoint list in the keywordquery result

Tags: 2010, search, managed-property, crawled-property, keywordquery

I have created custom search page in SharePoint 2010 in which `KeywordQuery` class is used. I want to get created date column of list in the result.

What I have done is created managed property and mapping it to crawled property `ows_Created_x0020_Date(Text)` and selecting that particular managed property as shown below in code:

```
KeywordQueryRequest.SelectProperties.Add("CreatedDateSearch");
```

But this is not helping me as in the output this column is coming blank. Can you please suggest how can I get the created date column as well in the result of KeywordQuery result.

I have tried mapping to below crawled properties

1. `ows_Created_x0020_Date(Text)` => No result/blank
2. `ows_start_x0020x_date(dt time)` => No result/blank
3. `ows_Created(Text)` => No result/blank
4. `Office:12(Date and Time)` => result is coming for this but it is not matching with actual created date of SharePoint list item.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding one more managed property maped to `Basic:15(Date and Time)` crawled property and did full crawl.

After full crawl page is throwing below exception

> "Your query included only common words and / or characters, which were removed. No results are available. Try to add query terms."

But on the next day, after scheduled full crawl at night same code is working and managed property which is mapped to `Basic:15(Date and Time)` crawled property has given correct created date column values.